# How to parse SOAP XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, soap

I have some SOAP responses saved in a file which I would like to parse,

Part of example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns0:GetList_Operation_0Response xmlns:ns0="urn:COMPANY:TEST:Assets" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ns0:getListValues>
            <ns0:Status>New</ns0:Status>
            <ns0:FormType>Support Group</ns0:FormType>
            <ns0:PersonRole>Supported by</ns0:PersonRole>
            <ns0:FullName>Data Centre</ns0:FullName>
            <ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>SG0003</ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>
            <ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>ASDAWDASDWADSDWSDWDS</ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>
            <ns0:AssetClassId>UPS</ns0:AssetClassId>
            <ns0:AssetInstanceId>ASDAWDDAWSDWADS66666</ns0:AssetInstanceId>
        </ns0:getListValues>
        <ns0:getListValues>
            <ns0:Status>New</ns0:Status>
            <ns0:FormType>Support Group</ns0:FormType>
            <ns0:PersonRole>Supported by</ns0:PersonRole>
            <ns0:FullName>Unix</ns0:FullName>
            <ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>SG0004</ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>
            <ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>ASDAWDASDWADSDWSDWQQ</ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>
            <ns0:AssetClassId>COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:AssetClassId>
            <ns0:AssetInstanceId>ASDAWDDAWSDWADS55555</ns0:AssetInstanceId>
        </ns0:getListValues>
    </ns0:GetList_Operation_0Response>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I would like to get (FullName & AssetInstanceId):

```
Data Centre;ASDAWDDAWSDWADS66666
Unix;ASDAWDDAWSDWADS55555
```

Could you suggest the best method to do that? Whenever I try to do that with ElementTree I get error of

```
"SyntaxError: expected path separator (:)"
```

Probably because of `ns0:` annex in beginning of every line

Comment: Looks like your xml is broken. You can try using regex to get the required values

Comment: Why do you think it's broken?

Comment: You can check it using an online xml validator

Comment: I've modified it to be able to show it in public, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: BTW Rakesh, how to use regex on the whole file if needed and not string?

Comment: The Ans should show how to use regex to get your required info

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your xml is broken. You can try using regex to get the required values

**Demo:**

```
a = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns0:GetList_Operation_0Response xmlns:ns0="urn:COMPANY:TEST:Assets" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns0:getListValues>
    <ns0:Status>New</ns0:Status>
    <ns0:FormType>Support Group</ns0:FormType>
    <ns0:PersonRole>Supported by</ns0:PersonRole>
    <ns0:FullName>Data Centre</ns0:FullName>
    <ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>SG0003</ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>
    <ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>ASDAWDASDWADSDWSDWDS</ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>
    <ns0:AssetClassId>UPS</ns0:AssetClassId>
    <ns0:AssetInstanceId>ASDAWDDAWSDWADS66666</ns0:AssetInstanceId>
</ns0:getListValues>
<ns0:getListValues>
    <ns0:Status>New</ns0:Status>
    <ns0:FormType>Support Group</ns0:FormType>
    <ns0:PersonRole>Supported by</ns0:PersonRole>
    <ns0:FullName>Unix</ns0:FullName>
    <ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>SG0004</ns0:PeopleGroupFormEntryID>
    <ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>ASDAWDASDWADSDWSDWQQ</ns0:PeopleGroupInstanceID>
    <ns0:AssetClassId>COMPUTERSYSTEM</ns0:AssetClassId>
    <ns0:AssetInstanceId>ASDAWDDAWSDWADS55555</ns0:AssetInstanceId>
</ns0:getListValues>"""

import re
FullName = re.findall("<ns0:FullName>(.*?)</ns0:FullName>", a)
AssetInstanceId = re.findall("<ns0:AssetInstanceId>(.*?)</ns0:AssetInstanceId>", a)
for i in zip(FullName, AssetInstanceId):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
'Data Centre', 'ASDAWDDAWSDWADS66666'
'Unix', 'ASDAWDDAWSDWADS55555'
```